# ASP.NET Membership API Equivalent for PHP

Tags: php

Are there any good schemas/models for roles and membership for PHP/MySQL, apart from rolling a custom one? I like the way ASP.NET's membership and roles work and was wondering of there was an equivalent in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at PEAR's [LiveUser package](http://pear.php.net/package/LiveUser).